# Injecting typeliased class parametrized by abstract type

Tags: generics, kotlin, dagger-2

I have a simple interface and class:

```
interface Foo {
    fun value(): Int
}

class FooImpl : Foo {
    override fun value() = 100
}
```

Now I want to create a factory for `Foo` and be able to inject it. I'm trying with following code:

```
interface FooFactory : () -> Foo

@Module
class AppModule {
    // provides FooFactory
    @Provides
    fun provideFooFactory() = object : FooFactory {
        override fun invoke() = FooImpl()
    }

    // uses FooFactory
    @Provides
    fun provideFoo(factory: FooFactory) = factory()
}

@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {
    fun foo(): Foo
}
```

And the place where `Foo` is injected:

```
@Test
fun test() {
    val component = DaggerAppComponent.builder().build()
    val foo = component.foo()
    Assert.assertEquals(100, foo.value())
}
```

Works perfect! However, I think, it's a kind of ugly to define `FooFactory` as an interface so I tried to replace:

```
interface FooFactory : () -> Foo
```

with:

```
typealias FooFactory = () -> Foo
```

And now I'm getting compile time error:

```
Error:Gradle:
  kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0<? extends net.chmielowski.daggerkotlin.Foo> 
  cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

If I understand it correctly, the problem is that `typealias` is inlined in the process of build (before Dagger code generation) and Dagger has a problem with finding out which provider provides instance for parametrized (generic) type `Function0<? extends Foo>` .

By the way: if I remove `Foo` and use just `FooImpl` everywhere, the problem does not occur. This mean that the problem is not with the generics itself but with the class parametrized by abstract type.

**What is the solution to this problem?**

To be clear - the rationale behind using `typealias` instead of `interface` is to be able to write:

```
@Provides
fun provideFooFactory() = { FooImpl() }
```

instead of:

```
@Provides
fun provideFooFactory() = object : FooFactory {
    override fun invoke() = FooImpl()
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but if you just want to inject a factory of foo you might want to use `Provider<Foo>`, where `provider.get()` will create new foos.

Comment: elegant solution. Does it work without typealias but only function types `() -> Foo`?

Comment: Provider is a class from dagger so there will be no function types involved. Instead of a factory class have a module that's responsible for giving you Foo. If you need a different implementation of Foo returned, switch out the whole module (use a different component with a different module that can provide Foo).

Comment: any updates for your problems here?

Comment: as suggested from official dagger issue: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/900#issuecomment-347081830 that `@ JvmSuppressWildcards` able to fix the issue. But wondering in your case is it works or not

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue today where I was using a kotlin lambda to return a value through dagger.

DaggerModule.kt

```
@Provides
fun provideFoo() = {
  foo.get()
}
```

BarClass.kt

```
BarClass( private val fooFunction: () -> Foo )
```

I was getting the same error you were seeing where dagger couldn't find the provided method.

(as above)

```
 kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0<? extends net.chmielowski.daggerkotlin.Foo> 
 cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

For me it was not enough to explicitly declare the type in the provider.
The solution instead had to do with how kotlin and java deal with generics.  Basically when translating that function into Java (which dagger still does under the hood) it was adding **< ? extends Foo>** to the method signature.  You can suppress this behavior with the **@JvmSuppressWildcards** annotation in the constructor of the receiving class.

```
BarClass( private val fooFunction: () -> @JvmSuppressWildcards Foo )
```

Comment: I still get the error, it reads `functions.Function0<kotlin.Unit> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method` now

Comment: In my case `@JvmSuppressWildcards` had to go before `()` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

The implementation

```
@Provides fun provideFooFactory() = { FooImpl() }
```

implies a return type of `() -> FooImpl` which would translate to `Function0<? extends FooImpl>` which dagger cannot match to `Function0<? extends Foo>`. Instead you have to make sure `provideFooFactory` has the correct return type.

This you can do by down-casting

```
@Provides fun provideFooFactory() = { FooImpl() as Foo }
```

or explicitly declaring the type

```
@Provides fun provideFooFactory(): FooFactory = { FooImpl() }
```

Comment: It haven't fix the problem, I'm still getting: `Error:Gradle: kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0<? extends net.chmielowski.daggerkotlin.Foo> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.`

Comment: What about using `typealias FooFactory = () -> @JvmSuppressWildcards Foo` instead?